# Port management strategy for Vagrant on Windows?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, chef-infra, vagrant

I was wondering if there is a community accepted pattern for managing vagrant port mappings? Auto correction is great, but it doesn't help with integration testing. In my case, I spin up multiple boxes, provision with Chef, and then run Serverspec.

You can see below, that with auto port assignments, the rake config file is no longer predictable when multiple boxes are used. Before I start another Yak shaving project, I was wondering how others handle this situation?

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
 config.vm.define 'wsus_server',primary: true do |config|
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 5985, host: 15985, auto_correct: true
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 3389, host: 13390, auto_correct: true
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 4000, host: 4000, auto_correct: true
 end

config.vm.define 'wsus_client' do |config|
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 5985, host: 15985, auto_correct: true
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 3389, host: 13390, auto_correct: true
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 4000, host: 4000, auto_correct: true
 end
end
```

serverspec (rake config):

```
require 'serverspec'
require 'winrm'

include Serverspec::Helper::WinRM
include Serverspec::Helper::Windows

RSpec.configure do |c|
  user = 'vagrant'
  pass = 'vagrant'
  endpoint = "http://localhost:15985/wsman"

  c.winrm = ::WinRM::WinRMWebService.new(endpoint, :ssl, :user => user, :pass => pass, :basic_auth_only => true)
  c.winrm.set_timeout 300 # 5 minutes max timeout for any operation
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the community accepted pattern for that these days is to use [Test Kitchen](http://kitchen.ci) instead of firing up individual VMs in Vagrant.

You can even use use the [kitchen-docker](https://github.com/portertech/kitchen-docker) driver to avoid firing up VMs at all. If you're on OS X or Windows, [dvm](https://github.com/fnichol/dvm) can help with creating a docker-server VM seamlessly for that.

You can also have a look at [meez](https://github.com/paulczar/meez) to get you started with that. I've written an [article on InfoQ](http://www.infoq.com/news/2014/02/meez) about that if you're interested.

Comment: Ah, but TK doesn't (yet) work against windows targets, unless they have SSH installed. /gone off to read your article/ thanks